# how to store multiple textbox values in array

Tags: vba

I have 5 textbox and in each I have to write the values, and all the value I want to store in to and array. 
this what i did

```
Dim arrayNames() As String = {CDec(txtName1.Text), CDec(txtName2.Text), CDec(txtName3.Text), CDec(txtName4.Text), CDec(txtName5.Text)}
```

Comment: Try this: `Dim arrayNames As Variant: arrayNames = Array(CDec(txtName1.Text), CDec(txtName2.Text), CDec(txtName3.Text), CDec(txtName4.Text), CDec(txtName5.Text))`

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array` function with a known set of items, as Victor notes in the comments:

```
Dim myArray() As String
myArray = Array(TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value, TextBox3.Value)
```

If you need to add dynamically to the array, then you can use `ReDim Preserve` statement, which resizes the array and preserves existing values:

```
Dim myArray() As String
myArray = Array(TextBox1.Value, TextBox2.Value, TextBox3.Value)

'later, add another element to the array:
ReDim Preserve myArray(Ubound(myArray)+1)
myArray(UBound(myArray)) = TextBox4.Value
```